# React Router Unable to navigate with Path parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I am having an issue navigating react router with path parameters

Here is my setup

```
render() {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path={Routes.PASSWORD_RECOVERY} component={ForgotPasswordView}/>
            <Route path={Routes.VERIFY_EMAIL} component={VerifyEmailView}/>
            <Route path={Routes.LOGIN} component={LoginView}/>
            <Route path={Routes.SIGN_UP} component={SignUpView}/>
            <Route path={Routes.VERIFY_RESULTS} component={VerifyGames}/>
            <Route path={Routes.HOME} component={Home}/>
            <Route path={Routes.WELCOME} component={Welcome}/>
            <Route exact path={Routes.DEFAULT} component={DefaultHome}/>
            <Route component={DefaultHome}/>
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

Here are my Routes

```
static readonly SIGN_UP = "/signup";
static readonly LOGIN = "/login";
static readonly PASSWORD_RECOVERY = "/password_recovery";
static readonly VERIFY_EMAIL = "/verify_email";
static readonly HOME = "/home";
static readonly WELCOME = "/welcome";
static readonly VERIFY_RESULTS = "/verifier";
static readonly DEFAULT = "/";
```

Now, I want to be able to navigate to the Verify games component which is on route path `/verifier`.

If I navigate to just `/verifier` it works, but if I append path parameters it doesn't navigate.

So, `/verifer` works, but `/verifier?name=mekings&&age=25` fails and always reroutes back to the DefaultHome Component

Why?

Comment: Can you provide what your path ENUMS are so it is clearer to us what the `Switch` is matching paths by? I don't see any overt issues. Can you duplicate your code into a minimal reproducible example *running* codesandbox and link in your question?

Comment: You're using <Switch> which renders only the first matching route. Make sure your route for `/verifier?name=mekings&&age=25` is above the route for `/verifier`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to úse your component as a child instead of a component prop?

Eg:

```js
<Switch>
<Route path={Routes.SIGN_UP}>
<Login view/>
</Route>
</Switch>

Please share your code on code sandbox if you still have issues.
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Both 2 ways are the same result

Comment: Alright. Check out the official docs [https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)